# Use Phonegap ChildBrowser Plugin to view in App PDFs on Android

Tags: android, cordova, childbrowser

I have the childbrowser plugin installed and working on my Phonegap application. Works fine for websites but I want to instead view PDFs which have been stored in my assets file.

The link I have to the pdf is currently

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage('file:///android_asset/pdf/Starting-Out_master.pdf');">Test</a>
```

But when I do this it trys to navigate to

```
http://file://android_asset/pdf/Starting-Out_master.pdf
```

How can I change the link to view the prepackaged PDFs?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot open a PDF using the ChildBrowser. You will need to use the PDF Viewer plugin. Here is a link, sorry that it is in  Italian you'll have to use Google Translate or something similar.

http://www.giovesoft.com/2011/08/download-and-open-pdf-with-phonegap.html

Answer (score 0):

Using the [WebIntent plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/WebIntent) may also work. Most (but not all) Android phones come with a PDF viewer built-in, so letting the Android OS decide what application installed on the phone to handle the PDF file should work in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the pdf file URI and open it with the childBrowser plugin's openExternal and let the native browser handle the PDF.